# Bootstrap 3 Menu is not collapsing on Ipad

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, navbar

I am doing a project using <strike>the new updated</strike> [Bootstrap 3 RC1](http://getbootstrap.com/).

There are may new features with the new Bootstrap 3 which are much different than the previous versions.
I figured most of the changes but one I can't resolve:

when the menu has many items it breaks in Ipad and other tablets becuase it doesnt get collapsed like it automatically collapsed on mobile (which is good)

I would like to know how do I "force" ipads to act like mobile and show a collapsed menu or better yet - how to collapse the menu if it has many items and on certain screens and smaller it breaks

here are screenshots of my live project:

**-- Menu on Big Screens --**

[image]

**-- Menu on Ipad Landscape --**

[image]

**-- Menu on Ipad Portrait --**

[image]

**-- Menu on Mobile --**

[image]

I simply want the ipad to act like mobile. notice that the portrait does act like mobile as far as the content but not the menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please read: http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/twitter-bootstrap-3-breakpoints-and-grid/

The collapsing of your menu is defined in the less files. (Download the latest version from:https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap )

In variables.less you will find `@grid-float-breakpoint:     @screen-tablet;` where  @screen-tablet is 768px.

So by default your menu will collapse when the screen width is below the 768px;

The ipad landscape has a screen width of 1024px so the menu will NOT collapse. The ipad portrait screen width is 768 px so the menu will NOT collapse.

See also navbar.less:

```
// Responsive navbar
// --------------------------------------------------

@media screen and (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
```

To change this behavior you have to change the @grid-float-breakpoint b.e set to 767 and recompile your css files.

NB You also mentioned: "notice that the portrait does act like mobile as far as the content but not the menu."

You use "col-lg-*" as prefix for your grid rows. "col-lg-*" elements will stack below the 992px (ipad portrait) and become horizontal above 992px (ipad landscape).

Comment: Do I have to include **less** folder to my project for that?  When I downloaded the files I didnt have a **less** file. I remember downloading only **css** and **js** folder.. Thanks

Comment: Fom the website: Until the final v3 is released, downloads may be behind the development branch and Bower package. So donwload from github: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/3.0.0-wip.zip

Comment: The problen is I am new to **less** and have no idea how to add it to my site and recompile my CSS. I'd be glad to have a link for a resource.  thanks!

Comment: Yeah if you have a dense header, you'll need precise breakpoints.

Comment: You'll miss a lot of other target devices. Apple's 768px width is not a standard for all tablets. Samsungs sticks to 800px for example. Maybe you should consider this in your solution.

Answer (score 9):

Just ran into this issue as well. I suggest you visit:

[Bootstrap customization](http://getbootstrap.com/customize)

Find the field `@grid-float-breakpoint` and set it to the screen width after which menu should collapse. There you could use variables from previous section, namely from `Media queries breakpoints` to set proper points.

Also, take a moment and check through all available variables to change. Creating a well-customized Bootstrap package might save you hours of dev. work, if not more.

Comment: @Maciej_Gurban I changed the grid breakpoint in the _variables file located in the bootstrap folder in Rails installer. How do I recompile my project so it uses that new breakpoint? I don't see any change in my views.

Comment: Have you checked http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1 ? There are also parts 2 and 3. Check which one applies in your case.

Answer (score 5):

For those poor souls who are not using less, you would have to modify the bootstrap.css and change media queries associated with navbar that have a breakpoint of 768px to 992 px.

For example, change

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

to:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The no less implementations I found didnt work

Couldn't find the styles to make this happen on its own anywhere, ended up finding this - https://coderwall.com/p/wpjw4w

Comment: Dude! Thanks for sharing, been fighting with this for like a day!

Comment: Works like  a charm! Anyone who doesn't want to recompile less files, go ahead with this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to correct our issue by changing the @media (max-width: 768px) query to 767px instead. One of the links above referenced a 1px issue on iPad which breaks differently and was forcing the mobile version of the website instead.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using the standard bootstrap.css file, I had to change it in 3 places:

around line 3780

```
/*changed from 768 to 992 */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .navbar-header {
      float: left;
     }
   }
```

around line 3799

```
 /* changed from 768 to 992 */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
```

around line 3924

```
/*changed from 768 to 992 */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
```

I hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite problem. On iPad the navbar was not collapsed (as expected), but the styles for a collapsed navbar were applied. I got it solved by changing the media query for the collapsed navbar adding `-1` to match with `$grid-float-breakpoint` as follows:

```
@media (max-width: $screen-sm-min - 1) {
//styles for collapsed navbar (which won't show up on iPad portrait)
}
```