# Bootstrap 3 Menu doesn't collapse at medium size

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, tablet

I am having issues with the collapsable menu working at a size above mobile. I want the site to be able to have the collapsable menu at mobile and portrait view for tablets, however once the site is resized to be bigger than mobile (where the mobile menu is still visible) the menu will show up, but the collapse function won't work. I shows the items that are supposed to be hidden, and when I click on the menu button to collapse it, it pops right back up again. I looked at [Bootstrap 3 Menu is not collapsing on Ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121893/bootstrap-3-menu-is-not-collapsing-on-ipad) but wasn't sure if this was related to my problem, and I couldn't make heads or tails of it.

The site I am working on is here: http://sculpturewalk.designangler.com/

Any advice would be great. I am still very new to responsive web design and Bootstrap. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have commented out `.navbar-toggle` css for desktop hide and using responsive utility classes. You just made that toggle button visible - you still have to extend styles for toggle dropdown as well. FYA, I didn't see any issues with toggle not working.

Comment: I just fixed it a short bit ago. I am working on issues with padding now.

Comment: You don't really have a toggle function issues anymore. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it after quite a bit of editing to the CSS. It was mostly figuring out which media queries I needed to change css for and I had to add a couple of float rules and make a couple of tweaks to get it working right. The biggest reason it wasn't working at all is because it had a rule of **display:block;** for screen sizes larger than 768px, removing that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: hey phorden, sorry but can you tell me which display block did u remove exactly?? thanks a lot

Comment: @alinem I would love to tell you but it has been so long since I have done this that I can't remember where I made the change.